# Angular 1/Jasmine/Karma - undefined is not an object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In my controller I have :

```
$onInit() {
  this.doShowInfoMsg()
}

doShowInfoMsg() {
  return this.checkProjectOnSalesLength = this.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectOnSales.length < 1
}
```

In my unit test (minimalist) :

```
describe('iadMyIadProjectMotivationsHowSaleCurrentCapitalDetail', () => {
      let scope
      let compile
      let element
      let ctrl

      beforeEach(() => {
        angular.mock.module('projectMotivationsHowSaleCurrentCapitalModule')
      })

      beforeEach(inject(($componentController) => {
        let bindings = {
          realEstateProjectMotivation: {
            realEstateProjectOnSales: [
              {
                id: 35,
                satisfied: true
              }
            ]
          }
        ctrl = $componentController('projectMotivationsHowSaleCurrentCapitalDetail', null, bindings)
      }))
    })
```

Error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectOnSales')
```

but when I do `console.log (ctrl.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectOnSales)` I have my array `realEstateProjectOnSales` that is well defined : `LOG: [Object{id: 35, satisfied: true}]`

Where can this error come from ?

Comment: `[Object{id: 35, satisfied: true}]` should be just `[{id: 35, satisfied: true}]`, without `Object`.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide What is the difference ?

Comment: My short answer is below

Answer (score 1):

`[Object{id: 35, satisfied: true}]` should be just `[{id: 35, satisfied: true}]`, without `Object`. `Object` is a constructor, so you trying to invoke this constructor wrong way. Look, with first structure it throws an error.

Wrong way:

```js
var foo = [Object{id: 35, satisfied: true}];
console.log(foo);
```

Right way:

```js
var foo = [{id: 35, satisfied: true}];
console.log(foo);
```

For more info about the Object constructor, which you was trying to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri, *"that is well defined : `LOG: [Object{id: 35, satisfied: true}]`"*. Where is it defined? I don't see such row in provided code

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
scope.project = {
  realEstateProjectMotivation: {
    realEstateProjectOnSales: [
      {
        id: 35,
        satisfied: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

because `realEstateProjectMotivation` referred to `real-estate-project-motivation="project.realEstateProjectMotivation"`